# how to set url-pattern in servlet

Tags: xml, gwt

I tried the same example in eclipse IDE by creating new GWT project its work fine but when i try to post the same concept into my project it doesn't work it return as following error

**"type Status report
message /cce/web/core/
description The requested resource (/cce/web/core/) is not available. "**

1. I set `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("marquee")`
2. in *.gwt.xml file module rename-to  set as `<module rename-to="core">`
3. in web.xml

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>marqueeServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/core/marquee</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

what i have to do

Answer (score 0):

Don't remap the servlet to the module.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>marqueeServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/marquee</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and just access it like  www.whatever.com/marquee

Answer (score -1):

Have you created Async interface for your service interface?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.